# Can't get title in view source using angular 5 universal

Tags: angular, express, angular5, angular-universal

Please follow my below thread, I tried searching alot online

[Header and Footer in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723857/header-and-footer-in-angular-5/)

Tried many examples :

https://angular.io/guide/universal
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly

I am able to see the  tag in the browser, but when not in the view-source.

Please suggest me a working example or a plunkr, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found working :

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

Answer (score 0):

you must include Angular universal so as to get the title & meta tags rendered in the page source.

Please follow this link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-fundamentals-universal-server-side-rendering

I too ran into the same issue during the past week & I solved it using the above things. Please follow the steps & you can get it rendered on the page as shown below

[image]

Comment: I tried this code, got alot of errror while executing the code,
author of this post has not updated the code, Its way different than his repo on github

https://github.com/LukasMarx/AngularUniversalGuide/

Comment: Please clone this repo & compare it with yours. I got this working with the above tutorials & I had attached the screenshot of the page source.

https://github.com/rogerjacob/ssr-demo-1