# Loading a component outside of root component

Tags: angular

I am loading all my `route` via root component called `AppComponent` (located in `app.component.ts`) as follows:

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-header></app-header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Everything is fine till now. But Now I want to load a `LoginCompoent` (at /login route) on entire page. Meaning there should is no `header` or `footer`, there should be just one component, `LoginComponent` loaded when I go to /login.

I know I can create a new root component which loads `AppComponent` or `LoginComponent` depending on  the `route`. But I was wondering if there is a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: Use a service to emit a boolean `BehaviorSubject` and hide your header/footer based on that value. You cant have a component outside root.

Comment: You can add `*ngIf*` at your app-header and app-footer components, but the best approach would be to separate your _in-app_ and _out-app_ components for many reasons.

Comment: Here is an example with regards to my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46049546/1791913

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am looking for some cleaner solution. Do you know how can I bootstrap second root component in angular? That would be a good clean solution

Answer (score 0):

Well the right way, as far as I know, is to do two separate modules for auth components and core components. And in the `app.component` you will have only `<router-outlet>` that will display auth or core. In the core you place all the components that should be displayed in your current structure

```
<app-header></app-header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

This way you will keep your app.component clean and you won't have any headache with the process.

[Here's the general idea](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmjusq) but I would recommend wrapping them into separate modules.

Comment: I understand that. I had already mentioned that approach in my question. I prefer some cleaner approach. As an example, having second root component.