# How to define routes for second root component in an Angular 6 Cli project

Tags: angular

Can someone tell how can I separately define routes for multiple `root components` in an `Angular6` + `angular-cli` project?

Currently, I have two root components `AppComponent` and `LoginComponent` and I am doing this to load these:

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-login></app-login>
</body>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, LoginComponent]
})
```

I have two queries:

1. How can I define routes for the second root component
2. How can I optionally load any root component depending on the routes?

Example: If I go to `/login` or `/login/conf1` only `LoginComponent` should be loaded. For other routes `AppComponent`

Surprisingly, there are no tutorials about multiple root component on the web or at least I couldn't find one.

My use case for two components: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150706/loading-a-component-outside-of-root-component)

Answer (score -1):

you should leave AppComponent as is, and create another component to deal with routes
you should have AppComponent, LoginComponent and AnotherOneComponent

in app.module.ts

```
@ngModule({
   imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
   ]
})

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: AnotherOneComponent
  }
];
```

in app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

if you want to handle sth like

```
/login/conf1
```

you'll be need to define child routes

Answer (score -1):

1. If you want child routes for a route you can do the following:

   `export const routes: Routes = [
           { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,
           children: [
             { path: 'one', component: SomeComponent},
             { path: 'two', component: SomeOtherComponent }
           ]
         }
       ];`
2. If you want to dynamically load a component based on the route you can inject the Router module in the `app.component.ts` file

`constructor(private router: Router){}`

and then in the html:

```
`
<app-login *ngIf="router.url != '/login' ></app-login>
`
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt answer the question. I am trying to have to root componets. Like AppComponent1 and AppCompoent2