# Angular 4 Reload header component from separate component

Tags: angular

I have a function that will require a seperate header component to refresh when its used.

**Foo Component** *(needs to reload header component)*

```
handleTimeListChange(value) {
    this.cp = value.
    localStorage.setItem('cp', this.cp);

    //reload header.component
  }
```

The result should be when time *handleTimeListChange* is used a call will reload (header.component)

Comment: why do you want to reload header.component is there nay reason?

Comment: I have some data in the header that will take the new setItem and refresh

Comment: currently if there is new data the header is not reflection on ui right?

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, so we can see the problem in a "real" context. Maybe a https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: correct but if I can reload the component it will be able to take that newly set data.   foo.component has handletimelistchange and header.component will need to reload when that item is set.

Comment: I think you don't need to reload the component, but just refresh the data. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the data will need to be refreshed

Comment: is there any relation between foo component and header component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem you can use rxjs SubjectBehaviour.make random service like this

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

    @Injectable()
    export class RandomService {

      private msgsource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('this is the default');
      telecast = this.msgsource.asObservable();

      constructor() { }

      editMsg(newmsg) {
        this.msgsource.next(newmsg);
      }

    }
```

This component from which you want to send the data, declare that service 
        method and and send the date to that method and where ever that service method is being called that data will reflect their.

```
      import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
        import { RandomService } from '../random.service';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-first',
          templateUrl: './first.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./first.component.css']
        })
        export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

          @Input('incomingmsg') newrandmsg: string;

          message: string;
          editedmsg: string;

          constructor(private someserv: RandomService) { }

          ngOnInit() {
          }

          editthemsg() {
            this.someserv.editMsg(this.editedmsg);
          }

        }
```

now receive that data to header component in ngOnInit that will detect any  value changes in that service method.

**HEADER COMPONENT**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.someserv.telecast.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
      }
```

> when ever any changes come under random service it will detect and show that data to header component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BehaviorSubject` for communicating within different components throughout the app. You can define a data sharing service containing the BehaviorSubject to which you can subscribe and emit changes.

see this ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46049546/4899523