# hide element on template into X component by Y component angular 7

Tags: angular, components, hide, angular7, show

I need to show/hide menu icon in menu.components by app.component

So my menu html component code:

```
<div class="menu-top" (click)="emitOpenMenu()"><!-- (click)="openMenu()" -->
  <div class="hamburgher-content">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="icon icon-sv-logo"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-bell" hidden="true" [routerLink]="'notifications'"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

My app.component code:

```
if (scanData === null) {
        menu hide
        // run code for hide menu icon here in menu compoonent
      } else {
        menu show
        // run code for show menu icon here in menu component

}
```

app.component html (parent)

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
      <div #target></div>
      <div *ngIf="showMenuBool">
        <sv-menu (openMenuOutput)="openMenu()"></sv-menu>      
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:60px;">
        <div class="fab-scan" *ngIf="showFab">
          <button mat-fab color="primary" (click)="openScanDialog()"><i class="fas fa-barcode"></i></button>
        </div>       
        <div class="fab-up" *ngIf="showUp">
            <button mat-fab color="primary" (click)="gotoTop(target)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></button>
        </div>
        <router-outlet (activate)="RoutesChanged()"></router-outlet>        
      </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

there is a way to get class by dom with angular ? I'm new about angular 7, thanks

Comment: Getting the DOM elements in code is not the Angular way of doing things. You should use `*ngIf` or `[hidden]` instead. Tell us under which condition each element should be shown or hidden.

Comment: hidden or ngif in the same component, i need to hide/show element by another component

Comment: If "another component" is the parent component, define `@Input` properties in the child, and bind these properties to values in the parent template. In the child, refer to the input properties with `*ngIf` or `[hidden]`.

Comment: I need to change element in the parent by child, there is a way ?

Comment: Please show the parent template, the child template, which elements must be shown/hidden, and under which conditons.

Comment: edited and added, the icon menu that i want hide/show it's inside sv-menu compoonent

Comment: See this to get an idea how you can share data between components: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46049546/1791913

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your  component is child component of a .
You can have variable inside app.component.ts like this:

```
menuVisible: boolean = true;
```

and the set this variable to true or false inside your method with if statement:

```
scanDataMethod(scanData) {
    if (scanData === null) {
        this.menuVisible = false;
    } else {
        menu show
       // run code for show menu icon here in menu component
       this.menuVisible = true;
    }
}
```

and then you can use this menuVariable as a @Input() inside **menu.component.ts**:

app.component.html:

```
<menu [menuVisible]="menuVisible"> </menu>
```

menu.component.ts:

```
@Input() menuVisible: string;
```

and you can use this menuVisible input variable inside **menu.component.html**:

```
<div *ngIf="menuVisible" class="menu-top" (click)="emitOpenMenu()"><!-- (click)="openMenu()" -->
    <div class="hamburgher-content">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
        <i class="icon icon-sv-logo"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
        <i class="fas fa-bell" hidden="true" [routerLink]="'notifications'"></i>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps!!