# How to go back without refreshing in angular 12

Tags: html, typescript, angular12

For example - there's a table in which I enter some value and proceed to next page, but when I come back to the page again I want the values entered to be there.
Currently I'm using this._location.back() but this doesn't show the changes rather refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **BehaviorSubject** for communicating between different components throughout the app. You can define a data sharing service containing the **BehaviorSubject** to which you can subscribe and emit changes.
**Define a data sharing service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataSharingService {
    public isUserLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}
```

See link for full solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047854/how-to-update-a-component-without-refreshing-full-page-angular)